# setLocation of graphic using x and y textField in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have this code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton button;
        private JTextField field,field2;       
        private JLabel labelx, labely; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test Frame = new Test();
        Frame.setSize(400, 400);
        Frame.createGUI();
        Frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createGUI(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        panel = new JPanel();       
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        window.add(panel);

        button = new JButton(); 
        button.setText("Teken water molecuul");
        button.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        button.addActionListener(this);     
        window.add(button);

                labelx = new JLabel("x");       
                field = new JTextField(2);
                labely = new JLabel("y"); 
                field2 = new JTextField(2);
                window.add(labelx);
                window.add(field);
                window.add(labely);
                window.add(field2);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {       
        Graphics paper = panel.getGraphics();
                String x = field.getText();
                String y = field2.getText();
                //panel.setLocation(x,y);                //this x and y don't work
                paper.setColor(Color.blue);
                paper.fillOval(50,50,50,50);
                paper.fillOval(50,200,50,50);
                paper.setColor(Color.black);
                paper.drawLine(92,92,150,150);
                paper.drawLine(92,207,150,150);
                paper.setColor(Color.red);
                paper.fillOval(100,100,100,100);

    }
}
```

I want to set the location of the graphic to a specific X and Y coordinates I got using two textFields. If I change the x and y manualy to a number, the white screen moves. I don't want to move the white screen but only the graphic.

So, the input of the two textFields should determine the position of the graphic.

Result when I run the code now. The position isn't determined by the input of the text textFields now.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bia0w.png]

Answer (score 0):

Custom painting is done by override the `paintComponent(...)` method of your panel, not by using the getGraphics() method.

So you need to create a custom class. This class would have two instance variables to control the x/y location. Then the painting code would reference these variables. You would also need to add a setter method to change the value of these variables.

The basic code would be something like:

```
public class CustomPainting extends JPanel
{
    private int locationX;
    private int locationY;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.translate(locationX, locationY)

        //  add your painting code here
    }

    public setGraphicLocation(int locationX, int locationY)
    {
        this.locationX = locationX;
        this.locationY = locationY;
        repaint;
    }
}
```

Then in the ActionListener code you need to invoke the setGraphicLocation(  ) method of your custom class using the value found in the text fields.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.